# How to replace images on Acumatica login page

Tags: acumatica

I need to replace images on the Acumatica login page with customization. I've tried creating a customization plug-in, but was not able to find the target with below code:

```
string targetDir = Path.Combine(PX.Data.Update.PXInstanceHelper.RootFolder, "Icons");
```

Let me know if there is another way to do this.

Comment: Any reason to not simply add your files in customization with proper paths? In what class/file are you currently doing `Path.Combine`?

Comment: I agree with Ruslan. You should be able to add the files in the instance location to a customization package. Put the files where you need in your site then in the customization add the files from the locations.

Comment: I am building a customization package to replace images displayed on login page. These images should be as per client so need to replace default images deployed with Acumatica.

Comment: These are under Icons folder (login_bg1.jpg, login_bg2.jpg, login_bg3.jpg, etc.) which I need to replace it while publishing customization. Hence I have already written CustomizationPlugin > OnPublished event. However, I need to get source directory which I have included in my customization project from where I can copy all files to default acumatica icons folder. Let me know if there is anyother way to do this.

Comment: If you include the images in a customization package then this will do it for you. The only issues is they will be replaced when you upgrade - just re-publish and you are good to go. No need to copy files. So in your test site, replace the images, then in the customization project, select those files for the customization project. Then export and you should have what you need.

Comment: @Brendan , Can you explain where I can include  images in customization package.

Comment: I see what you are saying about the standard file not including the image location. I will include an answer with a work around...

Answer (score 0):

> The following content is from "Replacing Images on the Login Page" from Stack Overflow Documentation
>   ([archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170816194706/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/acumatica/9657/replacing-images-on-the-login-page#t=201704072003213375539)); copyright 2017 by [RuslanDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929852/ruslandev); licensed
>   under CC BY-SA 3.0. An archive of the full Stack Overflow
>   Documentation content can be found at archive.org, in which this
>   example is indexed by its topic ID: 9657, as example: 29809.

To create a customization package replacing images on the login page, follow the steps below on your **local Acumatica instance**:

1. Create a new folder in the Acumatica instance folder. For this example I added a folder called ***IconsCustomized*** in my local **LoginImages** instance:

   [image]
2. Add your custom images in this folder. For the sake of this example, I used images from Acumatica 4.2 login page:

   [image]

   Keep in mind, ***to replace all images on the login page***, you have to add at least as many custom images in your **IconsCustomized** folder as the number of the `login_bg*.*` files originally present in the **Icons** folder of your Acumatica website. It's perfectly fine to use same image or images multiple times (by naming the files differently), if the number of your custom images is less then what was originally provided by Acumatica.
3. Now login to your Acumatica application, create new customization project called ***LoginPageImages*** and open it in Customization Manager.
4. In Customization Manager, navigate to the **Files** section and click the **Add New Record** button to open the **Add Files** dialog:

   [image]
5. In the Add Files dialog, select all files from your **IconsCustomized** folder and click **Save**:

   [image]

   ***Now you have the custom login page images in the customization project, but you still need to edit the path so they correctly replace the standard images.***
6. In Customization Manager, select **Edit Project XML** from the **File** menu:

   [image]
7. For all the **File** tags, generated for your custom images, charge the **AppRelativePath** attribute to ***AppRelativePath="Icons..."*** and set the **SystemFile** attribute to ***True*** for those images, that currently present in the **Icons** folder, then click the **Save to Database** button when done:

   [image]

   While publishing customization, Acumatica will automatically backup files currently present in the website folder, which are replaced by files from the customization with **SystemFile** attribute set ***True***.
8. If you now proceed with publishing the customization, it's very likely for **Some files have been modified in the file system.** error message to show up. To prevent this quite frightening message from appearing, open you project in Customization Manager, navigate to the **Files** section and click **Detect Modified Files** to open the **Modified Files Detected** dialog, then click the **Discard All Changes** button:

   [image]
9. Now you can go ahead and publish the customization to enjoy your custom images on the login page:

   [image]