# How do I change the login screen images with a customization project?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

When I login in Acumatica, my users see the default Acumatica images and I would like my own branding instead.

How do I  replace the login screen's images with my own ?
How can I do that so for hosted ans SaaS environments ?

Comment: There is a similar Q&A here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209817/how-to-replace-images-on-acumatica-login-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To customize the login screen for your own hosted or SaaS environment, you will have to develop a customization project on your local environment. The following guide will tell you how to replace one of the login image and the logo shown on the login screen.

#### The first step is to modify your local environment files.list file.

It is located at the root of your site (e.g. YourAcumaticaSite\files.list).
For my example, I need to remove Icons\login_bg1.jpg and Icons\login_logo.png from files.list.  Save the file.

[image]

#### Now go to your local site Icons folder (e.g. YourAcumaticaSite\Icons ) and replace the same two files (login_bg1.jpg and login_logo.png) with your own images.

It is important to keep the exact same file name.

[image: Site/Icons folder]

#### For the next step, go on your local site customization project screen (SM204505) and edit/create the customization project that will contain these new images.

Go in the Files section, click on the Add button (+) and select the two new images.

[image: Add to project]

#### Save the project, export it and publish it on your staging/production environment.

You can now admire your new login screen.

[image: Result]

If the images shown are still the old ones, your browser might have cached the images. To clear your favorite browser cache, follow instructions found here : https://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/

Once you are done, you can go back to your local website to edit the files.list file and put back the lines we previously removed.